# Strictly compare all elements of two lists in python without considering their order

Tags: python, list, set

How to compare each value between the lists. It should be exact match.

```
list1 = ['same1', 'same2']
list2 = ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 = ['same1', 'same2']

def comp(list1, list2, list3):
    if set(list1) & set(list2):
        print  "Train A is active and instances are %s." % list2
    elif set(list1) & set(list3):
        print  "Train B is active and instances are %s." % list3
    else :
        print "No Trains are active"
comp(list1, list2, list3)
```

Above code still returns Train B as active despite I have one different value in `list3 = ['not_same1', 'same2']`

Looks like it is just checking for one value from the list, how do I compare all the elements even though elements are no in order.

Looks like `**set**` is getting deprecated, any other way for doing this is welcome.

Comment: For comparison of values I'd imagine you want `==`. From your question it's not entirely clear what output you are expecting.

Comment: `set()` is not getting deprecated. Python2 is.

Comment: Above is a example lists, I am comparing two lists (list2 and list3) with master list (list1). If I find a match, print the matching list as active.

Comment: *"Looks like `set` is getting deprecated"* I didn't heard about that, and I do not think it is ever going to happen, *atleast not very soon*.

Comment: set is **very definitely not** getting deprecated.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri 'set' became a builtin type in 2.4 (might be as early as 2.2) - prior to that there used to be a 'sets' module which had a 'Set' class. As Daniel says - it's not going anywhere.

Comment: To clarify, do you want `['same2', 'same1']` to equal both `['same2', 'same1']` AND `['same1', 'same2']`, OR should `['same2', 'same1']` NOT be equal to `['same1', 'same2']`? Your question isn't completely clear on this, at least to me.

Comment: Your output is correct. list1 and list3 do match

Comment: `list3` does not contain `'not_same1'`.

Comment: In his example code, list1 and list3 are the same. However, he then later says "Above code still returns Train B as active despite I have one different value in list3 = ['not_same1', 'same2']". This is wrong, list3 is actually ['same1', 'same2']

Comment: @JontyMorris and @user2357112, I assume that what he means is that when he alters one of the values in `list3` to `not_same1`, the code still returns Train B as active. Not that `not_same` is a member of `list3` in his posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare sets directly with `==`. Since sets remove multiple values, check if both lists are of the same lengths first before attempting to convert to them sets:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def comp(list1, list2, list3):
    if len(list1) == len(list2) and set(list1) == set(list2):
        print("Train A is active and instances are %s." % list2)
    elif len(list1) == len(list3) and set(list1) == set(list3):
        print("Train B is active and instances are %s." % list3)
    else :
        print("No Trains are active")
```

Run some test:

```
def test(list1, list2, list3):
    print('#' * 10)
    print('list1', list1)
    print('list2', list2)
    print('list3', list3)
    comp(list1, list2, list3)

list1 = ['same1', 'same2']
list2 = ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 = ['same1', 'same2']
test(list1, list2, list3)
list2 = ['same1', 'same2']
test(list1, list2, list3)
list2 = ['same1', 'same2', 'same2']
test(list1, list2, list3)
list2 = ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 = ['same1', 'same2', 'same2']
test(list1, list2, list3)
```

Output:

```
##########
list1 ['same1', 'same2']
list2 ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 ['same1', 'same2']
Train B is active and instances are ['same1', 'same2'].
##########
list1 ['same1', 'same2']
list2 ['same1', 'same2']
list3 ['same1', 'same2']
Train A is active and instances are ['same1', 'same2'].
##########
list1 ['same1', 'same2']
list2 ['same1', 'same2', 'same2']
list3 ['same1', 'same2']
Train B is active and instances are ['same1', 'same2'].
##########
list1 ['same1', 'same2']
list2 ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 ['same1', 'same2', 'same2']
No Trains are active
```

Answer (score 1):

Use equality check `set(list1)==set(list2)` instead of intersection `set(list1) & set(list2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `==` will give you what you want. It directly compares the values of two sequences:

```
list1 = ['same1', 'same2']
list2 = ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 = ['same1', 'same2']

def comp(list1, list2, list3):
    if list1 == list2:
        print(  "Train A is active and instances are %s." % list2)
    elif list1 == list3:
        print(  "Train B is active and instances are %s." % list3)
    else :
        print( "No Trains are active")
comp(list1, list2, list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do I compare all the elements even though elements are no in order.

Here's a way to compare the 3 arrays without using **set**.

```
def compareArrays(list1, list2):
    for item in list1:
        if not item in list2:
            return False # The array's don't match
    return True # The array's match

def comp(list1, list2, list3):
    if compareArrays(list1, list2):
        print(  "Train A is active and instances are %s." % list2)
    elif compareArrays(list1, list3):
        print(  "Train B is active and instances are %s." % list3)
    else:
        print( "No Trains are active")

list1 = ['same1', 'same2']
list2 = ['notsame1', 'notsame2']
list3 = ['same1', 'same2']

comp(list1, list2, list3)
```